# Mailing lists / Usenet groups for research math

Tags: discussion, communication

For Category theory there is a well known and quite active research mailing list https://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/ Do similar mailing lists or usenet groups exist for other branches of mathematics? For example in metric geometry, conformal geometry,... Or do most research related discussions now take place on MO?

Comment: There certainly exist mailing lists for some areas, for example, [foundations of mathematics](http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/), [Banach spaces](https://www.mathdept.okstate.edu/pipermail/banach/) or [algebraic topology](https://lists.lehigh.edu/pipermail/algtop-l/). I do not know about the areas you mentioned in your post.

Comment: Doesn't this question fit better on main than here on meta?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just moved it here because on main it was argued it fits better on meta :)

Comment: Hmmm. meta is for questions about the operation of main,  so I don't see it. Anyway, there's a Number Theory listserve, NMBRTHRY@LISTSERV.NODAK.EDU, but it's pretty low-volume.

Comment: The AMS once had a page where mailing lists on mathematics areas were listed.  But I looked just now and did not find it.  So: I guess mailing lists, although popular in the last century, are little used today.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Here is link to the question on the main: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267537/research-mailing-lists-usenet-groups (Deleted at the moment, so visible only to 10k+ users and the OP.)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a list of some mailing list for specific areas of mathematics. (This is posted as a [community wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-wiki/info), if you are aware of some other mailings lists, do not hesitate to add them to the list. And also if you have some additional useful information related to some of the lists.)

- FOM -- Foundations of Mathematics - [basic info](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/mailman/listinfo/fom), [archive](http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/). This mailing list has been mentioned quite often [in MO posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=pipermail+fom+site:mathoverflow.net) and [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=pipermail+fom), including citations in some [books](http://books.google.com/books?q=pipermail+fom) and [papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=pipermail+fom).
- Banach -- Banach Space Theory News - [basic info](https://www.mathdept.okstate.edu/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/banach), [archive](https://www.mathdept.okstate.edu/pipermail/banach/)
- ALGTOP-L -- Algebraic Topology Discussion Group - [basic info](https://lists.lehigh.edu/mailman/listinfo/algtop-l), [archive](https://lists.lehigh.edu/pipermail/algtop-l/)
- Categories List (category theory) - [basic info](https://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/), [archive until 2009](https://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/#archives)
- <s>Real Analysis List</s> - [basic info](http://www.math.louisville.edu/~lee/rae/rafaq.html) (now very likely defunct - see [GEdgar's comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3214/mailing-lists-usenet-groups-for-research-math/3219?noredirect=1#comment14271_3219))

Comment: I did not find any archive for [Real Analysis List](http://www.math.louisville.edu/~lee/rae/rafaq.html) online and I am not a subscriber. If somebody has more information about that list, please do add it to the post. (Especially knowing whether it is still active would be useful.)

Comment: I am also able to find some individual messages from category theory mailing list [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gmane.science.mathematics.categories%22+site%3Apermalink.gmane.org) but I did not find some kind of index for the whole archive [from here](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories). Also [this link is dead](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories), but it [used to have some archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20160716083322/http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories).

Comment: That's the thing with a mailing list: it is a mailing list, not an archive.  I am a subscriber to the Real Analysis list, but have received no messages for years.  So I guess it is defunct.

Comment: There's a finite group mailing list, but it's not archived on the open Web like fom, categories or ALG-TOP. It's website is also hopelessly out of date.

Comment: There's also constructivenews, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/constructivenews for constructive mathematics of varying flavours; HoTT-Cafe for homotopy type theory for non-experts (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hott-cafe) and homotopytypetheory for experts (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/homotopytypetheory). The finite group one is http://people.bath.ac.uk/masgcs/gpf.html or something like it, I think.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Feel free to add the mailing lists which you consider interesting/useful enough. (I made the post CW as a way to encourage other users to edit it, if they have something worth adding.)

Answer (score 3):

Sci.math, sci.math.research, alt.sci.(whatever) are some of the newsgroups that dealt with mathematics and various branches. You can find histories of them and other information on them with web searches.

The unmoderated groups became spam wastelands, especially after Google instituted their version called Google Groups.  I left sci.math for this reason, and only looked sparingly at sci.math.research, which was moderated. When Kevin Buzzard posted in s.m.r. about MathOverflow back in 2010, I tried it, and have not looked back since.

If you frequent some older web pages (using the Wayback Machine, for example), you will find references to mailing lists and other resources.  It seems that blogs and forums and YouTube are the current means of idea exchange; (as I believe Gerry Myerson might say) I will be surprised if you find many active mailing lists.

Gerhard "The Technologies, They Are A-Changing" Paseman, 2017.04.18.

Comment: You are attributing to me opinions which I have not expressed. I have no basis for an opinion on the number of active mailing lists in Mathematics. I limited my comment to the one mailing list with which I have some experience.

Comment: @Gerry, I apologize.  I will edit the post to reflect my beliefs.  Gerhard "Feel Free To Not Express" Paseman, 2017.04.18.